# how i can programmatically close rdp connection

Tags: c#, rdp

I have an application on the server. I can connect to it using rdp, but under some circumstances(request from client, for example) I need the service to close the connection. How can I detect an existing rdp connection and close it if it has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

windows utility tsdiscon can do this

```
Process.Start(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess
   ? Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%windir%\sysnative\tsdiscon.exe")
   : "tsdiscon.exe");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following code. I tried at my side and it is working.

Package : **using System.Diagnostics;**

```
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("mstsc");
    int pid = processes[0].Id;
    Process pro = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
    pro.Kill();
```

Comment: nope, processes.Lenght is 0

Comment: then process mstsc is not running or run you program as an admin.

Comment: i think mstsc is not running, but i still connect to my remote pc, idk how it work :/

Comment: could you please share the application name? By which application or software are you using to connect remote?

Comment: mstsc.exe but this is on my computer, I need to close the connection from the remote computer